# I have a column in table named "client_name".... i need to select column value from last row in my join query

Tags: join, select, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

i have table with column name policy_refer, client name and issue_date

```
policy_refer    Client_Name   issue_date(entry_date)
0001             Ajaz         01-Jan-2019
0001             Ajaz         05-Jan-2019
0001             Anita        10-Jan-2019
```

i want to select last update/insert client_name where policy_refer = 0001 , in my select/join query ....

```
select policy_master.CLIENT_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number
      ,policy_master.policy_refer
      ,policy_master.POLICY_CLASS
      ,policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT
      ,policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE
      ,policy_master.EXPIRY_DATE
      ,sum(policy_master.TOTAL_SUMINSURED)
      ,sum(policy_master.GROSS)
      ,sum(policy_master.PERMIUM)
from POLICY_MASTER,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL
where policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER
and POLICY_MASTER.POL_ID = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POL_ID
and POLICY_MASTER.EXPIRY_DATE ='19-AUG-20'
and POLICY_MASTER.DOC_STATUS ='Posted'
group by POLICY_MASTER.policy_refer
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number
        ,policy_master.policy_refer
        ,policy_master.EXPIRY_DATE
        ,policy_master.CLIENT_NAME
        ,policy_master.POLICY_CLASS
        ,policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT
        ,policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE;
```

Comment: What result you are getting from above query?

Comment: i get client_name Ajaz.. but the last client_name is Anita .. according to issue date

Comment: Please do not significantly change your question. If you want to ask a different question then ask it in a different question rather than overwriting your existing one.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to find which one's the first (using analytic functions), and then fetch that row. For example:

```
select column_list_goes_here
from (
        --> this is your current query, with the ROW_NUMBER addition
        select all your columns here,
        --
        row_number() over (partition by policy_refer order by issue_date desc) rn
        --
      from your_tables
      where ...
      group by ...
      --> end of your current query
      )
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the table you are talking about is the `POLICY_MASTER` table and you want the latest row (by `ISSUE_DATE`) for each policy.

Then you want to filter something like this:

```sql
select pm.CLIENT_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number
      ,pm.policy_refer
      ,pm.POLICY_CLASS
      ,pm.POLICY_PRODUCT
      ,pm.P_ISSUE_DATE
      ,pm.EXPIRY_DATE
      ,sum(pm.TOTAL_SUMINSURED)
      ,sum(pm.GROSS)
      ,sum(pm.PERMIUM)
from   (
         SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT POL_ID,
                  CLIENT_NAME,
                  policy_refer,
                  POLICY_CLASS,
                  POLICY_PRODUCT,
                  P_ISSUE_DATE,
                  EXPIRY_DATE,
                  TOTAL_SUMINSURED,
                  GROSS,
                  PERMIUM,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY policy_refer /*, pol_id */
                                      ORDER BY ISSUE_DATE DESC ) AS rn
           FROM   POLICY_MASTER
           WHERE  EXPIRY_DATE = DATE '2020-08-19'
           AND    DOC_STATUS  ='Posted'
         )
         WHERE rn = 1
       ) pm
       INNER JOIN POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL pid
       ON (     pm.policy_refer = pid.POLICY_REFER
            AND pm.POL_ID       = pid.POL_ID )
GROUP BY pm.policy_refer
        ,pid.INSURER_NAME
        ,pid.INSURER_BRANCH
        ,pid.policy_number
        ,pm.policy_refer
        ,pm.EXPIRY_DATE
        ,pm.CLIENT_NAME
        ,pm.POLICY_CLASS
        ,pm.POLICY_PRODUCT
        ,pm.P_ISSUE_DATE;
```

Comment: qurey giving ----ORA-00904: "PM"."POL_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 35 Column: 17

Comment: @EjazSarwar You haven't given any sample data or DDL statements for your tables so it is difficult to test. However, if you look for the `pm` table alias and find the sub-query that represents and see if there is a `POL_ID` column in the query (there wasn't but I've now edited it in) then you can debug that error yourself.

Comment: can you tell me how i can get the row where is higher like

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need the first row after sorting them in descending from issue date -

```
select policy_master.CLIENT_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH
      ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number
      ,policy_master.policy_refer
      ,policy_master.POLICY_CLASS
      ,policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT
      ,policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE
      ,policy_master.EXPIRY_DATE
      ,sum(policy_master.TOTAL_SUMINSURED)
      ,sum(policy_master.GROSS)
      ,sum(policy_master.PERMIUM)
from POLICY_MASTER,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL
where policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER
and POLICY_MASTER.POL_ID = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POL_ID
and POLICY_MASTER.EXPIRY_DATE ='19-AUG-20'
and POLICY_MASTER.DOC_STATUS ='Posted'
and rownum = 1
group by POLICY_MASTER.policy_refer
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH
        ,POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number
        ,policy_master.policy_refer
        ,policy_master.EXPIRY_DATE
        ,policy_master.CLIENT_NAME
        ,policy_master.POLICY_CLASS
        ,policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT
        ,policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE
ORDER BY P_ISSUE_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: `ROWNUM` is generated before `ORDER BY` is applied. Your query will not work as it will return the first row and then it will sort that single row (rather than ordering the rows first and then getting the first row).

Comment: @MT0, Agreed. Was in too much hurry.